# Predicting with two classes in machine learning

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

```
def convertDCM(PathDCM) :
   data = []  
   for dirName, subdir, files in os.walk(PathDCM):
          for filename in sorted(files):
                     ds = pydicom.dcmread(PathDCM +'/' + filename)
                     im = fromarray(ds.pixel_array) 
                     im = keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(im)
                     im = cv2.resize(im,(300,300))
                     data.append(im) 
   return data

PathDCM = '/home/Desktop/FULL_BALANCED_BW/'

data = convertDCM(PathDCM)

class_names = ['Normal','Abnormal'] #Normal = 0, Abnormal = 1

read = pd.read_excel('/home/FULL_REDUCED_BALANCED_DATA.xlsx')
labels = read.iloc[:,2].tolist()

#scale the raw pixel intensities to the range [0,1]
data = np.array(data, dtype="float")/255.0
labels = np.array(labels,dtype ="uint8")


#splitting data into training and testing

(trainX, testX, trainY, testY) = train_test_split(
                            data,labels, 
                            test_size=0.2, 
                            random_state=42) 

img_width, img_height = 300, 300 #InceptionV3 size

train_samples =  1000
validation_samples = 200
epochs = 10
batch_size = 32

base_model = keras.applications.InceptionV3(
        weights ='imagenet',
        include_top=False, 
        input_shape = (img_width,img_height,3))

#Classifier Model ontop of Convolutional Model
model_top = keras.models.Sequential()
model_top.add(keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D(input_shape=base_model.output_shape[1:], data_format=None)),
model_top.add(keras.layers.Dense(450,activation='relu'))
model_top.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.5))
model_top.add(keras.layers.Dense(1,activation = 'sigmoid'))
model = keras.models.Model(inputs = base_model.input, outputs = model_top(base_model.output))

#Compiling model using Adam Optimizer 
model.compile(optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(
                    lr=0.00002,
                    beta_1=0.9,
                    beta_2=0.999,
                    epsilon=1e-08),
                    loss='binary_crossentropy',
                    metrics=['accuracy'])

#Image Processing and Augmentation 
train_datagen = keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(
          zoom_range = 0.1,
          width_shift_range = 0.2, 
          height_shift_range = 0.2,
          horizontal_flip = True,
          fill_mode ='nearest') 

val_datagen = keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator()


train_generator = train_datagen.flow(
        trainX, 
        trainY,
        batch_size=batch_size,
        shuffle=True)

validation_generator = val_datagen.flow(
                testX,
                testY,
                batch_size=batch_size)

#Training the model
history = model.fit_generator(
    train_generator, 
    steps_per_epoch = train_samples//batch_size,
    epochs = epochs, 
    validation_data = validation_generator, 
    validation_steps = validation_samples//batch_size)
```

When predicting the probabilities for two classes I use:

```
testX= convertDCM('home/Desktop/NewData')
testX = np.array(testX, dtype="float")/255.0

predictions= model.predict(testX)
print(predictions)
```

And get returned this array:

```
[[0.6151286 ]
[0.5269037 ]
[0.6088796 ]
[0.55031174]]
```

Since I only have two classes, is the returned number the probability that it belongs to the first class? Meaning the class at element 0 (Normal)? So by this thinking, anything less than 0.5 is Normal and anything greater than 0.5 is Abnormal?

Comment: what is textX? what is model?

Comment: That is really up to interpretation.  Without seeing the code, you are probably getting the the probability of the test sample belonging to the abnormal case, with `1-p_normal` being the probability of the other class.  You are not getting good separation between the two classes at only ~0.6, but this may be enough for your specific case, that is where the interpretation comes in.  This is a very broad question.

Comment: I've updated the post to include my code.

Answer (score 1):

The returned number is the probability of predicting the positive class (encoded as 1). In your case, this is probably the class `Abnormal` (it depends on how your data is encoded exactly). You can convert the predicted probabilities to binary values by calling:

```
(predictions > 0.5).astype(int)
```

Answer (score 1):

The four numbers correspond to four inputs you have the model.

Each number is encoded the same way as the target was during training (trainY). If class 1 was encoded as the target `0` and class 2 was encoded as `1`, then you can interpret the output value `0.6` as a probability of 0.6 that it is class 2.

Please note that you might see the following cases in production that you cannot deal with:

- It is neither class 1 nor class 2 - the network will still assign one class at least 50% probability as it cannot do different
- It is both, class 1 and class 2 - the network will at best assign each class a probability of 50%.